# The behavior of $\sin {\omega t}$ at relativistic frequencies

Tags: special-relativity, angular-velocity

The product $\omega t$ is a dimensionless quantity and the same is true for $\sin{\omega t}$. If they are dimensionless, then they are identical between the rest and relativistic frames because there is no dimensions of time or length to dilate or contract.

This represents a circle rotating about a fixed center with $\omega$ providing a constant angular velocity so the tangential velocity along the circumference is at relativistic speeds.

[image: Figure 15.4.1 : SHM can be modeled as rotational motion by looking at the shadow of a peg on a wheel rotating at a constant angular frequency.]

What am I missing?

Edit: Part of my confusion is the relationship between $\pi$, the period T and the angular velocity $\omega$:

$2 \pi = \omega T = \omega' T'$ and the $\gamma$ terms cancel

So let's add an amplitude:
$$ f(t) = A \sin \omega t$$
At relativistic frequecies:
$$ f(t') = A' \sin \omega' t'$$

Evaluating for a period:
$$ f(T) = A \sin \omega T$$
$$ f(T') = A' \sin \omega' T'$$
Cancelling the sin terms and rearranging for amplitude leads to:
$$ A'= A \frac{f(T')}{f(T)}$$
Does amplitude change or does $A' = A$?

Comment: Dimensionless quantities don't change under *rescaling* transformations of coordinates, but they can (and do) change under *Lorentz* transformations. Quantities that don't change under Lorentz transformations are called [Lorentz scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_scalar), and $\omega t$ is not a Lorentz scalar.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. Does this mean that any time based dilation is applied to $\omega$ only?

Comment: Time dilation is only part of the story. Both space and time transform under a boost. What will happen is that $\omega t$ will transform into something like $\omega' t' - \vec{k}' \cdot \vec{x}'$, so you will have a function of space and time, with a different frequency in the boosted coordinate system.

Comment: $\sin{\omega t}$ is distance in angle covered. All distances covered are relative things, IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

$\omega t$ is indeed an invariant quantity. $\omega$ is rotations per unit time and $\omega t$ is simply rotations. If you are moving relative to me and make 3 complete rotations in your reference frame and return to your original position, I will agree that you made 3 complete rotations. We will disagree on how long you took to make those rotations and so we will disagree on $\omega$.

For example if you are observing an object that is rotating with an angular velocity of N rotations per second about a centre that is not moving relative to you, then I will measure the angular velocity to be (N revolutions per second)$/\gamma$. The difference in observed angular velocity is entirely accounted for by time dilation and the number of revolutions (N $= \omega t$) is the same in both of our reference frames.

$\sin(\omega t) $ is a more complicated animal. Angles are ratios of lengths and due to length contraction, the lengths parallel to the relative motion contract and lengths orthogonal to the motion do not. The units of an angle (L/L) are dimensionless, but the angle is not invariant under transformation. This means we can't assume that being dimensionless means being invariant. It is not a universal principle.

This is also complicated when there are successive non parallel boosts and Thomas rotation takes place, but that is another kettle of fish.

> *"ω is rotations per unit time and ωt is simply rotations"*. It would be
> more accurate to replace the word "rotations" with "radians".
> Rotations per unit time implies revolutions per second where the
> corresponding quantity would be frequency rather than angular
> frequency ω. –  joseph h

I used the phrase "rotations per unit time" to imply complete revolutions or average angular frequency as measured by an observer at one point on the circle that observes a point on the rotating object to pass him and then waits for the point complete a full rotation and take another reading with the same clock. Angular frequency is a bit more complicated for small angles because as I mentioned above, angles are not invariant and the angular frequency of a point on the rotating object is continually changing according to another reference frame depending on where the particle is at any instant. Its a bit like trying to quantify the instantaneous tangential velocity of a point on a car tyre in the rest frame of the road. Monetarily it is stationary at the contact point of the road and a moment later it is twice the velocity of the car at the top of the rotation. Its possible to solve, but usually unnecessarily complicated to be generally useful.

Comment: Part of my confusion is the relationship between $\pi$, the period T and the angular velocity $\omega$:

$2 \pi = \omega T = \omega' T'$ and the $\gamma$ terms cancel.

Comment: $2 \pi = \omega T = (\omega' \gamma ^{-1}) (T' \gamma) = \omega' T'$ is in fact correct. I added a paragraph to my answer about the sin($\omega T$) case that might be of interest.

Comment: _ω is rotations per unit time and ωt is simply rotations._ It would be more accurate to replace the word "rotations" with "radians". _Rotations per unit time_ implies _revolutions per second_ where the corresponding quantity would be frequency rather than _angular_ frequency ω.

Comment: @josephh Added a bit to address your valid point.

Comment: The opening paragraph of this answer is incorrect. $\omega t$ (for constant $\omega$) is the angle, which you correctly note in the third paragraph is not invariant.

Comment: I don't understand what "I will agree you made three rotations" means. Three rotations... at which point in time? Whose time?

Comment: Let's say we have a rocket that travels from Earth to Mars and it rotates 1000 times about its axis parallel to the path, during the journey, perhaps to provide artificial gravity. If you and me are in different inertial reference frames we will disagree on the time the journey took and we will disagree on the distance between Earth and mars due to length contraction, but we will both agree it made 1000 revolutions during the journey.

Comment: I've edit my question for clarification. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Dimensionless doesn't mean Lorentz invariant. Given some reference frame with time coordinate $t$, $t/(1\text{ s})$ is dimensionless. It is not necessarily equal to $t'/(1\text{ s})$ where $t'$ is the time coordinate of another frame.

Comment: Part of my confusion is the relationship between $\pi$, the period T and the angular velocity $\omega$:

$2 \pi = \omega T = \omega' T'$ and the $\gamma$ terms cancel

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your description of the "value" of the function is correct. However, the invariant under Lorentz transformation is $\omega t$, and neither $\omega$ nor $t$ alone. That is, for observers in different frames, the "frequencies" observed are different.

Comment: Part of my confusion is the relationship between $\pi$, the period T and the angular velocity $\omega$:

$2 \pi = \omega T = \omega' T'$ and the $\gamma$ terms cancel

Comment: Intuitively, you can imagine $\omega$ as the "multiple" of $2\pi$ in a unit time interval with respect to a reference frame chosen by the observer. As a result, you may expect that the $\gamma$ factor is cancelled out finally.

Answer (score 0):

$\omega t $ is not invariant.

Pre-emptive sanity check: second hands are things with angular velocities and we know lots about clocks.

If we set units of $\text{minute} = 1$ and $\omega = 2 \pi$, we're watching at the second hand of a clock. Put the clock upright and make it translate along the x axis with the velocity pointing in the direction of 3 o'clock. The clock will be squashed in the x direction and we'll measure one revolution every $t'=\gamma (t-vx/c)$ minutes. Which is to say, the angular displacement of the second hand in the primed frame $t' \omega'$ should differ from $t \omega$ such that the above ratio holds. If the clock is moving away from us, we should always measure *less* angular displacement.

If we start the at the origin with constant velocity (and take the length of the second hand to be negligible) then $t' = \gamma (t-vx/c) = \gamma t(1-\beta ^2)$ which is nice because it should let us replace $t'\dfrac{\delta}{\delta t'}$ with $t \dfrac{\delta}{\delta t}$, having gotten rid of $x(t)$.

Negative $\beta$, since the clock is moving away from us.

---

$t'\dfrac{\delta  \theta'}{\delta t'} = t'\dfrac {\delta}{\delta t'} \arctan ( \dfrac{\sin(\omega t)}{\gamma \cos(\omega t) - \beta}) = f(t)$

$f(t) = t\dfrac {\delta}{\delta t} \arctan ( \dfrac{\sin(\omega t)}{\gamma \cos(\omega t) - \beta})$

$ = \dfrac{tω (-β \cos(\omega t) + γ \sin^2(\omega t) + γ cos^2(\omega t)))}{(β^2 - 2 β γ cos(\omega t) + γ^2 cos^2(\omega t) + sin^2(\omega t))}$

Back to sanity check values with $\text{minute} = 1$ and $\omega = 2 \pi$. Set $t=1$ and simplify to get 1 revolution worth of proper time.

$ f(1) = \dfrac{2\pi (\gamma -β)}{(β^2 - 2 β γ + γ^2)} = \dfrac{2\pi}{(\gamma -β)}$

I couldn't find anything canonical about Lorentz-transformed angular velocity that didn't involve tensor calculus that I didn't understand, so I'm not 100% confident in this result. But this reduces to what we'd expect in Galilean relativity in the $\gamma \approx 1$ domain, which makes my sanity like it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found my error. In a linear frame at rest an observer sees an object approaching at a constant relativistic v. But a person on the object will see the observer moving at the same velocity. So v = v'. I believe the same is true for angular velocities so $\omega = \omega'$

Evaluating for a period:
$$ f(T) = A \sin \omega T$$
$$ f(T') = A' \sin \omega T'$$

So $$ f(T') = A' \sin \gamma \omega T$$  or

$$ f(T') = A' \sin \gamma 2\pi$$